# Hbase Error creating a table

Tags: hbase

I am fairly new to HBase and have encountered this issue while creating a table.

Statement:

```
create 'table1', {Name=>'info'}
NameError: uninitialized constant Name.
```

Appreciate any quick help on this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the available [hbase shell](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#shell) commands, I believe the syntax should be:

```
create 'table1', {NAME =>'info'}
```

Replace the period with a comma.

Comment: Thank you for the response Elena..It  was a typo and I used ',' itself. Is there something else that I should be looking for?

Comment: I'm a little stumped. My Google foo is no good on this one. :-/

Comment: I restarted the ZooKeeper process along with Hbase master. Things seem work fine. Thanks.